# Shadow of Partially immersed pole

Tags: geometric-optics

I read that shadow is formed at opposite end if the sun rays are coming at an angle towards us [image]Something like the above picture.But now while I'm studying geometric optics in a question where i need to calculate the height of shadow of the partially (and equally )immersed pole. My textbook says the shadow(of the part of the pole in water) will be formed on opposite to part of pole in the air.I failed to understand why?Even though rays are coming at slightly different angle why will the shadow be formed at the opposite end

Comment: I suggest that you draw a picture with the sun's rays striking the pole directly *and* underwater.  You will see that the rays in the air are all parallel, including the rays that will bend at the water's surface before they reach the pole.  The same is true of the rays propagating in the water.  Do the drawing carefully, and probably the answer will become obvious to you.